# What's the best alternative to using triggers in MYSQL for better scaling?

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers, database-administration, database-trigger

We have multiple scrapers hitting our MYSQL database at the same time, updating lots of rows continuously.
Each table has triggers that evaluate the UPDATE sent by the scrapers, and as we progress into the project we are having more and more conditions to verify in each update inside the triggers and so we are having fears that this is not a good way to scale.
The main table has triggers that sends data to another table that also have triggers, that sends to one more that has triggers.

We are thinking about several options to avoid overhead, table locking or that kind of trouble.

By now we believe that we need to abandon MYSQL or to put another database engine in the middle as queue and process the information with Python or Node instead evaluating the data there and inserting directly/updating only when necessary.

Also, since we have mostly writes, we are having issues scaling and avoiding to have a huge monolith, but as of now we don't have a good plan.

I have google a lot for ideas about a good architecture for this, most of the recommendations seems to go away from RDBMS.

TLDR: The core question would be, what's the best way to avoid overhead caused by triggers in multiples tables in multiples with several conditions to evaluate? Is using something else to process the data better?

Comment: I would look at Redis, and Pull logic out into middleware instead of triggers, which hide logic. But to fully answer your question, i couldnt give a solid answer apart from hunches sorry

Comment: I would ask this kind of thing in dba

Comment: Are you *sure* that triggers are a problem? And not the amount of data you write, and would still have to write with alternative systems.

Comment: Need more details.  What kind of updates?  "Likes"?  lat/lng location of a vehicle?  Online/offline?  What?  Do the updates come in batches?  Or one at a time?  Would it be easy to intercept them?  Is Replication involved?  Etc, etc.  There is no "one size fits all" for your question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of updates. @RickJames it's for price tracking and calculations based on them. We can do one at the time or in batches, currently is one at the time. Currently we have no replication.

Answer (score 0):

use listeners on your framework, if you are creating or updating a records in a specific entity. Make a listener to the specific entity, to insert a new record on the corresponding table.This will be avoid errors on the triggers

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that your scrapers process the data to decide what to do with it.  Either they can do the necessary `SELECTs` and `UPDATEs`, or they can pass the numbers on to some other process that can batch them up for bulk `INSERT` (or whatever).

With something like that, you can have multiple processes on multiple servers doing the scraping (until you get blocked as a DOS attack) and munching on the data.  Then they can calmly update the data on the database.

The reason for suggesting this approach is that you the processes can scale arbitrarily, but writes to a database cannot.